# Go hours minutes and seconds to just minutes with Date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API where they send me the format `00:25:00` and this I have to pass to a format that looks nice: like this 25:00 min what I had done is this way

```
const date = new Date("00:25:00");
{format(date, "h:m ")}
```

but I get an error, and I don't know how to pass this format 00:25:00 to minutes

Comment: Is the only thing you need to do remove seconds from time format you receive?

Comment: if remove the seconds and spend hours and minutes to just minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested the below one, but just try getting the minutes and seconds

```js
const date = new Date();
const newdate = ("00" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
console.log(newdate);
```

If you mean to just minutes then remove the `.getSeconds()`